# Why does this return a list of characters instead of a string in Python when iterating a dictionary using items()

Tags: python, items

Python question:

Why does this return a list of characters instead of a list of the keys as strings?

```
d = {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'aaa', 'key3': 'bbb'}
a=[]

for k,v in d.items():
    a += k

print(a)
```

I received the following result:

['k', 'e', 'y', '1', 'k', 'e', 'y', '2', 'k', 'e', 'y', '3']

Comment: Use `append`, not `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `+=` operator in lists expects an iterable, resulting in a concatenation of that iterable into the list. A string is an iterable of its chars.

To have the results you expect, do either:

```py
a.append(k)
```

or

```py
a += [k]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()` to append `k` to `a` list:

```
d = {'key1': 'aaa', 'key2': 'aaa', 'key3': 'bbb'}
a=[]

for k,v in d.items():
    a.append(k)

print(a)
```